# Best practices for defining FastImageCache FICImageFormats?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview

I'm using Path's `FastImageCache` library (https://github.com/path/FastImageCache) in order to have pre-resized images cached ready for use in `UIImageView`s.

To use FIC, you define `FICImageFormat`s which include a bunch of data, including the image size. In order for best performance, this image size should be identical to the size of the `UIImageView` that the image will be used in.

This gives rise to a chicken-and-egg sort of problem: should the code that sets up FIC (in the `AppDelegate` or wherever you do the rest of your basic init work for your app, presumably?) know the sizes of the `UIImageView`s in the rest of your app? This has the obvious downside of very tight coupling of your app's startup code with UI implementation details.

An alternative is that you could have your UIs implement a protocol that defines a method such as

```
+(NSArray *)imageFormats;
```

which would return an array of `FICImageFormat` objects representing all image formats that would be required by that bit of UI. Then the startup code would only have to know which classes implement that protocol in order to get a full list of image formats required for the app.

This second approach has the downside of potential duplicate `FICImageFormat`s. It would be non-optimal to have two (or more!) image formats for the same image format family that also have the same dimensions. Then you'd be caching the exact same data more than once.

Any other approaches you can think of? Best practices? All thoughts are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think what could help here is to start at the design level - you should agree with the designers for a certain set of image formats for any image family and then you would have a central list of all your image formats and families in your style guide anyway.

It doesn't matter then so much if your code is in the AppDelegate or in the View layer, because neither the view layer nor the startup code really determine which formats exist, but your style guide. It's not an implementation detail anymore, but part of an external specification.